# How to quit a job after two months?

Tags: job-change

I started a new job two months ago and so far it's going good - I really like the people I work with, which is what makes this so hard. I used to work at another firm (accounting so same job) about 5 years ago and I had to leave because I moved away. I stayed in good contact and about four years ago I started chasing a job with them. I've been chatting to them regularly but in the past four years no suitable position has come up. Well they called me two days ago and sent me an offer straight away, I don't need to interview or anything and I have accepted it.

The new job offers me paid study leave to finish my degree, flexitime, more money, they will pay for further qualifications and to top it off it's walking distance from my house.

I need to hand in my weeks notice at my current job today but I'm afraid because I don't want to stress anyone out. What's the best way to approach it?

Comment: After 2 months, it shouldn't take too much handing over your workload.  Give your notice, serve it out by doing a clean handover and enjoy your new role.

Answer (score 6):

Do it politely.

Respect the time others have given to mentor you in the past 2 months and thank them. If you are questioned about your motives, a simple "I have found a better opportunity for myself" will do. In return, people will respect you.

Comment: If you are questioned about your motives, a simple "I have found a better opportunity for myself" will do.
aka   the "Its not you, its me" breakup excuse approach.